# I am a South African travelling to the USA via Amsterdam - Do I need another visa to pass through Amsterdam if I do not leave airport?

Tags: transit-visas, netherlands, south-african-citizens

I am a South African travelling to Chicago, I have a  valid 10-year visa for the USA but my flight is from Johannesburg to Amsterdam airport, onward to Chicago. Do I need another visa for the fact that I am landing in Amsterdam? I do not have a valid Schengen visa currently.

Comment: Standard question: Is this booked as a single ticket or two separate ones ?

Answer (score 1):

South Africa is not on the list of countries that must hold an airport transit visa when transiting through the *international* parts of airports in the Schengen area.

Source: https://home-affairs.ec.europa.eu/policies/schengen-borders-and-visa/visa-policy/who-must-apply-schengen-visa_en and https://www.netherlandsworldwide.nl/visa-the-netherlands/airport-transit-visa

If your itinerary is booked as two separate trips and you *need to leave the international parts of the airport* to collect checked luggage before your on bound flight, you can use this official tool https://www.netherlandsworldwide.nl/visa-the-netherlands to check if you need a visa in order to clear Immigration.

Comment: "you can use this official tool...": Which will say that a visa is necessary unless one of several unlikely exceptions applies, for example if the traveler is traveling with a diplomatic passport or has an unmentioned Schengen residence permit.